# Visualization issue of dtreeviz framework

Tags: python, machine-learning, visualization

here is my code run in pycharm and it is supposed to display nice visualization chart, but no result is shown

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydotplus
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
from io import StringIO
from ipywidgets import Image
from dtreeviz.trees import *
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# fit the classifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
viz = dtreeviz(clf,
               x_data=X_train,
               y_data=y_train,
               target_name='class',
               feature_names=iris.feature_names,
               class_names=list(iris.target_names),
               title="Decision Tree - Iris data set")
plt.show()
```

for example  i am using this  link for reference
https://github.com/erykml/medium_articles/blob/master/Machine%20Learning/decision_tree_visualization.ipynb
even i run this code in google colab, no result is shown in google colab too, so what is wrong? output of this code is just this:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the `dtreeviz` part of the code (looking at the GitHub notebook) will only work if you have GraphViz installed and on the path. Do you?

Comment: yes it is installed

Comment: Is it on the path? If it is (or after you've put it on the system path), try calling `viz.view()` instead of `plt.show()`. For me, that generates and opens (in another application) a .svg. For me it opens in InkScape, so you may need to configure or install a viewer for .svg (a browser should work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mixing some parts of the example code (and is including some parts that aren't needed).

If you run the below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dtreeviz.trees import dtreeviz
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = load_iris()
x = iris.data
y = iris.target
x_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=42)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

viz = dtreeviz(clf,
               x_data=x_train,
               y_data=y_train,
               target_name='class',
               feature_names=iris.feature_names,
               class_names=list(iris.target_names),
               title="Decision Tree - Iris data set")
viz.view()
```

And providing you have all the referenced packages installed, as well as [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/download/) and GraphViz was configured to be on the PATH (before you started your editor / IDE), then calling `viz.view()` will generate and launch a .svg file.

If you have an application configured for viewing .svg (like a web browser, or InkScape, etc.) it should show the result you're after.

(Note that I also ran this code from PyCharm, on Python 3.10.8 - any 3.10 should work - using a recent version of all the packages and a fresh install of GraphViz.)

You can check if GraphViz can be run by opening a terminal in PyCharm and running: `dot -V`. You should see something like:

```
dot - graphviz version 6.0.2 (20221011.1828)
```

Comment: wow, i have never seen viz.view(),thanks for help

Comment: i have done it already