# Pycharm not showing dtreeviz

Tags: scikit-learn

I have an issue with dtreeviz in Pycharm 2022.3 Professional Edition.
I've followed the suggestions in [Visualization issue of dtreeviz framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090617/visualization-issue-of-dtreeviz-framework).
Graphviz is installed and in the path. There appears to be a tree_vix object.

The code runs fine but there is no tree displayed. Default browser is Edge using Windows 11.

Any ideas much appreciated.

The code is:

```
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier,plot_tree
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
    import dtreeviz

    X = dfl_tree.drop('Result', axis=1)
    y = dfl_tree['Result']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    dt_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)

    param_grid = {
        'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
        'max_depth': [None, 3,4,5],
        'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
        'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 5]
    }

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(dt_classifier, param_grid, cv=5)
    grid_search.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)

    best_dt_classifier = grid_search.best_estimator_

    y_pred = best_dt_classifier.predict(X_test)


    # Output the decision tree as a graph using dtreeviz
    feature_names = X_train.columns.tolist()

    tree_viz = dtreeviz.model(
        best_dt_classifier,
        X_train.values,
        y_train.values,
        target_name='Result',
        feature_names = feature_names,
        class_names=['No further action','Positive result'],

    )

tree_viz.view()
```